# Javfx Native bundle on Windows server 2003 doesn't work

Tags: java, windows, javafx, java-8

I created a native bundle of my app for Windows@32 bit. I used Jdk 8u40 b23.

After the installation of my Javafx app on a Windows server 2003, a double click on the .exe file don't work. Nothing happens.

On the opposite, installing the jdk 8u40 b23 and double clicking on the .jar file, the app starts.

I know that Windows server 2003 is not official supported from Java8; but someone can explain me if there is a workaround to make it work?

The same native bundle 32bit works on Windows Xp!

Thanks

Comment: Try check OS Event Logs (they can contains description of your problem) or try to run application from console (probably will be written some exception to STDOUT).

Comment: Unfortunally I yet tried this. No logs in OS Event Logs, neither logs on stduout running .exe file from dos prompt.

Comment: May be you are  using x64 JRE in package for x86 OS. Try to check this.

Comment: Yet checked. Infact on a WinXp the app works. In my runtime folder I've WindowsAccessBridge-32.dll. So I'm using 32bit bundled jre

Comment: ok, lets try to check where is a problem (in exe perloader or application). 1) Remove JDK from OS (after that you should reproduce problem described above). 2) Add any code which can check that your Java application is running (i.e. create file) to `main` function. 3) Add handler `Thread#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler` for main thread and save exception to file too. So, the problem in exe perloader if you won't see any your files created after running exe preloader.

Comment: This app hasn't preloader. I'm using log4j so a log file shuld be created asap the app starts, but in my case is not created when I run directly the .exe file.

Comment: Could it be a permission problem?

Comment: I tried also that but nothing. Maybe simply it is a bug in the packager of JavaFx

Comment: Are you using antivirus? May be it block your exe. Try to add exe to exception list of antivirus.